# Why does the first item run as $i in my foreach list end up blank or mixing in with the next item in the list?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Basically this just uses powershell to query for the members of a group and sort the results. If I do one command at a time it works fine, but when I add it to a script, the first entry ends up blank or mixes some of the first users with the second entry of the foreach...

```
import-module activedirectory

$share = get=content "list.txt"

foreach ($i in $share){
get-adgroupmember $i | sort | select-object samaccountname,name
}
```

Comment: It should be fine, try just `foreach($i in $share){$i}` to see what happens. Are you running this in ISE or how are you running the file?

Comment: `get=content` should also be `get-content`!

Comment: Running from admin command prompt in powershell.  Most of the script works fine, it's just the first entry that gets wonky. The $1 reports correctly

Comment: yeah sorry, that was a mistype on my end. it IS "$share = get-content"

Comment: Is your text file, `list.txt` saved with a BOM, by any chance? A Byte Order Mark, _(a three byte leading sequence `0xEF`,`0xBB`,`0xBF`, for UTF-8)_, could possibly corrupt your first line.

Comment: You may have empty lines or whitespaces around the entries of your input list.txt file. Try `$share = (Get-Content -Path "list.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }).Trim()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that you want a report of all **user** objects in a group (`Get-ADGroupMember` can return users, computers or groups) and want the SamAccountName and Name properties of these users in the result.

Because your code does not also return the name of the share itself, there would be no way of telling which users are a member of which group, so that would explain what you mean by *"mixes some of the first users with the second entry of the foreach"*.

Also, as commented, you may have empty lines or leading/trailing whitespaces around (some of) the items in the text file.

Try:

```
# read the group names from the file. 
# skip empty lines and make sure the names are not surrounded by whitespace
$groups = (Get-Content -Path "list.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }).Trim()

$result = foreach ($group in $groups) { 
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | 
    Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'} |
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = {$group}}, SamAccountName, Name |
    Sort-Object Name
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-List

# output to csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\Groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

As for the output, you woud like it formatted differently.
You can be as creative as you like once you have the objects stored in the `$result` variable.

Something like:

```
# group the results by the Group (share) property
# and output the usernames beneath that group name
$result | Group-Object Group | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    # output the group (share) name with a dash line beneath it
    "{0}`r`n{1}" -f $_.Name, ('-' * $_.Name.Length)
    # next output the usernames
    foreach ($user in $_.Group) {
        '{0}, {1}' -f $user.SamAccountName, $user.Name
    }
    # output an empty divider line
    ''
}
```

Of course you can also capture this output and display later or save as text file

```
$final = $result | Group-Object Group | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object { .. }

# show on screen
$final

# save as file
$final | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\GroupsFinal.txt'
```

Output would look something like

```
ShareGroup1
-----------
jdoe, John Doe
hbloggs, Henry Bloggs

ShareGroup2
-----------
ppicasso, Pablo Picasso
```

Comment: The above works. I would rather that it listed the name of the share and then the users underneath it. in format: username, actual name

Comment: @Max I have added code to format the results as you would like.